# How to plot this BVP using shooting technique there is a problem in selecting the initial guess

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-condition-at-infinity, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the flow and heat transfer problem. I am using the following code

```
    Clear[max, Pr, S, T, f, \[Eta], p, phi, rhos, rhof, M, epsilon, 
  rbetas, rbetaf, A, B, J];
max = 50; rhos = 5180; rhof = 997; epsilon = 0.5; M = 0.5; rbetas = 
 0.5*10^-5; rbetaf = 1.3*10^-5; Pr = 6.2; phi = 0.05;

A = 1/(1 - phi)^2.5
B = 1 - phi + phi*(rhos/rhof)
J = 1 - phi + phi*(rbetas/rbetaf)
pohl = NDSolve[{A f'''[\[Eta]] + B f[\[Eta]] f''[\[Eta]] - 
      B (f'[\[Eta]])^2 + B epsilon (S[\[Eta]])^2 - M f'[\[Eta]] + 
      J T[\[Eta]] == 0, 
    A S''[\[Eta]] + B f[\[Eta]] S'[\[Eta]] - 
      B 2 f'[\[Eta]] S[\[Eta]] - M S[\[Eta]] == 0, 
    T''[\[Eta]] + 2 Pr f[\[Eta]] T'[\[Eta]] == 0, f[0] == f'[0] == 0, 
    f'[max] == 0, S[0] == 1, S[max] == 0, T[0] == 1, T[max] == 0}, {f,
     S, T}, {\[Eta], max}];

pohl2 = NDSolve[{A f'''[\[Eta]] + B f[\[Eta]] f''[\[Eta]] - 
     B (f'[\[Eta]])^2 + B epsilon (S[\[Eta]])^2 - M f'[\[Eta]] + 
     J T[\[Eta]] == 0, 
   A S''[\[Eta]] + B f[\[Eta]] S'[\[Eta]] - B 2 f'[\[Eta]] S[\[Eta]] -
      M S[\[Eta]] == 0, T''[\[Eta]] + 2 Pr f[\[Eta]] T'[\[Eta]] == 0, 
   f[0] == f'[0] == 0, f'[max] == 0, S[0] == 1, S[max] == 0, 
   T[0] == 1, T[max] == 0}, {f, S, T}, {\[Eta], max}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
     Thread[{f[0], f'[0], f''[0], S[0], S'[0], T[0], 
        T'[0]} == ({f[0], f'[0], f''[0], S[0], S'[0], T[0], T'[0]} /. 
         First@pohl)]}]

p4 = Plot[{Evaluate[f'[\[Eta]] /. pohl]}, {\[Eta], 0, max}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 18}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "f'[\[Eta]]"}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

How to plot  the equations by giving an appropriate initial guess. Also while compiling i get the following errors

- Set::write: Tag  Plus in 0. +0. +0.520978 S[[Eta]]^2+0.993846 T[[Eta]]+1.04196 f[[Eta]] (f^[Prime][Prime])[[Eta]]+1.02544 (f^(3))[[Eta]] is Protected. >>
- Set::write: Tag Plus in 0. -0.5 S[[Eta]]+1.04196 f[[Eta]] (S^[Prime])[[Eta]]+1.02544 (S^[Prime][Prime])[[Eta]] is Protected. >>
- Set::write: Tag  Plus in 12.4` f[[Eta]] 
  T^[Prime][[Eta]]+T^[Prime][Prime][[Eta]] is Protected. >>
  ReplaceAll::reps: {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {0. +0.60489 S[[Eta]]^2+0.969231 T[[Eta]]+1.20978 f[[Eta]] (f^[Prime][Prime])[[Eta]]+1.13682 (f^(3))[[Eta]]==0,0. -0.5 S[[Eta]]+1.20978 f[[Eta]] (S^[Prime])[[Eta]]+1.13682 (S^[Prime][Prime])[[Eta]]==0,12.4 f[[Eta]] (T^[Prime])[[Eta]]+(T^[Prime][Prime])[[Eta]]==0,0==(f^[Prime])[0],True,True,True,True,True}. >>

Comment: I put semicolons after where you assign A,B,J. I don't get your errors. What I do get are some warnings from FindRoot failing to converge, NDSolve "boundary values not satisfied to tolerances" and  about a stiff system warning, but I do get a plot at the end.

Comment: Try running your code in a fresh kernel, I'm not getting those errors. You probably have previously defined some of the functions used here and MMA is complaining about it.

Comment: How to plot the function f ''[eta] when eta tends to zero in the same code